# How to Type URL using Robot class in Java

Tags: java, keypress, keyevent, awtrobot, keyrelease

I want to create program which can type automatically using following methods:

```
robot.keyPress(code);
robot.keyRelease(code);
```

but i can not press Any Special Characters, It throws `Exception` like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
at mypkg.GooglePiano.type(GooglePiano.java:65)
at mypkg.GooglePiano.<init>(GooglePiano.java:45)
at mypkg.GooglePiano.main(GooglePiano.java:16)
```

I want to type : **http://google.com/?q=pratik+butani** but its print ***http*** only.

Please help me

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_8);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

When you try to type '*' from keyboard, you pres shift+8. Same key storkes should be simulated.
Similar way can be used for any special characters.